# JQuery Animation Flashing

Tags: jquery, animation

Is there any way to keep this simple JQuery animation from flashing? http://jsfiddle.net/v3DVf/6/

Comment: what do you mean by flashing? it doesn't flash for me

Comment: I suppose it's browser dependent. I'm running Chrome and it flashes pretty badly when if I scroll too quickly...

Comment: I just tried IE, which is really bad...

Comment: if you increase the `top: (300 - (1.5 * $(window).scrollTop())) ` 0.5 to 1.5 its better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because you're scrolling too fast for jQuery to calculate everything. This seems to help:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#left').stop().animate({
        top: (300 - (0.5 * scrollTop))
    }, 350);
    $('#right').stop().animate({
        top: (300 - (0.2 * scrollTop))
    }, 350);
});​
```

That's caching the scrollTop value rather than recalculating, and omitting the (true, true) from the stop function.

EDIT: Also, get rid of the #container css call, just make it `position: fixed`.

Comment: Yep. Between using a variable and setting #container to fixed, it seems that the flashing issue is solved. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/v3DVf/10/